# Create a multi option string type from specific key from given object

Tags: typescript

The first example is something I experimented with but didn't succeed, the example below is what I need, the object can also have other keys that should be ignored I need in the end a type that gives me all options from all 'name' keys like mentioned below // "Peter" | "Alex"

```js
// base I use to try to achieve my goal
type Pair = {
  key: string;
  value: number;
};
function craetePairsArray<T extends readonly Pair[] & Array<{key: V}>, V extends string>(...args: T) {
    return args
}

const pairs = craetePairsArray(
  { key: 'foo', value: 1 },
  { key: 'bar', value: 2 },
)

type Keys1 = typeof pairs[number]['key'] // "foo" | "bar"

/**
 * WHAT I REALLY WANT & NEED
 */
const data = {
  props: {
    name: "peter",
    children: [
      { props: { name : "Alex", children: null}}
    ]
  }
}

/**
 I want to be able to create a type like: "Peter" | "Alex" from craetePairsArray(data)
 */
const pairs = craetePairsArray(data)
```

[PLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECMEMGcFNQJKgK51AFwPYYE4E9RoBjACwEsA3MgOwHNQBbA2zSAGwFgAodPAB3gAFSGRygAvKADe3UKADWsPAC5C6HDVoBuWaArtksVdWQNwsHDq4BfKwDNk1IujKZqoIjkix0sYaOgAQRwvPAAeABVQWAAPX2oAE2hQHFhIBLc2An8cAG0AXVAAMlBg0LCpRRVQADVrAD4AGlrouNhE5Oh1TXqACgA6QcgcWmhVCIBKaV05VPRkHHdh0e5rbm4iNy7QPhEcZMlPb18coJDIPF7dKQUlVQByO0xMe%20b9NkNVAEZQa0br27Ve5QHCvPQGIygABMv3%20XAm6x4-HgAGklNAfpJeAJMHYdntoLkTGYLPlcvcqvdCiBQAAiJ6YWmgAA%20dJBtMRwAAVFzZFzQAB1AASgSiSAASgBRQIAGRlAE1BYEAHJRErKyWSgAifOAGy26FACUg6EgEmmXDkfBwmD4Ywtcjk1EgDEhtIEvhwtLhjo85DYCVS1FUuRmjpu1tt9puztdoFUtMCbFi3r9ZADQeMyDYbGsa0tjvyunz%20c5PNkSAA7pBqIajj4-ASyhcMNg5gslhhkaA2GRFAnBA2vSy6UmU4iPF4G6dm5djaaEZauXquNwgA)